# C++ PixelComponent struct

Tags: c++, validation, template, interval, overloading

Hey I wrote a struct in C++ trying to represent a Pixel Component of a color
Here it is

```
template<typename T, T min, T max>
struct PixelComponent {
    static constexpr T MIN = min;
    static constexpr T MAX = max;
    T value;

    PixelComponent() = default;

    PixelComponent(T value) : value(value) {}

    inline bool operator==(const PixelComponent &other) {
        return value == other.value;
    }

    inline bool operator!=(const PixelComponent &other) {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    inline bool operator>(const PixelComponent &other) {
        return value > other.value;
    }

    inline bool operator<(const PixelComponent &other) {
        return !(*this > other) && *this != other;
    }

    inline bool operator>=(const PixelComponent& other){
        return !(*this < other);
    }

    inline bool operator<=(const PixelComponent& other){
        return !(*this > other);
    }

    inline PixelComponent &operator=(const T &elem) {
        if (value == elem) {
            return *this;
        }
        value = elem > MAX ? MAX : elem < MIN ? MIN : elem;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent &operator=(const PixelComponent &other) {
        if (*this == other) {
            return *this;
        }
        *this = other.value;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent &operator++(){
        *this = ++value;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent &operator--(){
        *this = --value;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator+(const T& elem){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value + elem;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator-(const T& elem){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value - elem;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator*(const T& elem){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value * elem;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator/(const T& elem){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value / elem;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator+(const PixelComponent& other){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value + other.value;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator-(const PixelComponent& other){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value - other.value;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator*(const PixelComponent& other){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value * other.value;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator/(const PixelComponent& other){
        PixelComponent result;
        result = value / other.value;
        return result;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator+=(const T& elem){
        *this = *this + elem;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator-=(const T& elem){
        *this = *this - elem;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator*=(const T& elem){
        *this = *this * elem;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent operator/=(const T& elem){
        *this = *this / elem;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent& operator+=(const PixelComponent& other){
        *this = *this + other;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent& operator-=(const PixelComponent& other){
        *this = *this - other;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent& operator*=(const PixelComponent& other){
        *this = *this * other;
        return *this;
    }

    inline PixelComponent& operator/=(const PixelComponent& other){
        *this = *this / other;
        return *this;
    }


};

template<typename T, T min, T max>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const PixelComponent<T, min, max> &component) {
    os << component.value;
    return os;
}
```

Please review this. I will be thankful for any suggestion or typos noticed) Please also review implementation of `value` always staying in range `[MIN,MAX]`. I have not added that validation in constructor, is there a nice way to do that?

Comment: The code looks great. No need for `inline` request, code in a class declaration are inlined by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why?**

I don't see any benefit to using this `PixelComponent` class over simply using the value type directly, because...

---

**Clamping**

... clamping to min and max values is less helpful than it appears.

We might want a color to be clamped to the range `0.f` to `1.f` in our output. However, it's very useful to do calculations with colors outside of that range as an intermediate step (e.g. `(a + b) * 0.5f`). Clamping prevents us from doing that.

Alternatively, if we were using a `std::uint8_t` as a color component (range `0` to `255`), clamping the value would be meaningless as we're already using the full range of the type (and misleading, since we'd overflow before the clamping occurred).

So ultimately I'd suggest doing the clamping explicitly, when we need to as part of our color manipulation algorithm, and not in the pixel type itself.

Note also that we can use `std::clamp()`, rather than writing our own clamping function.

---

**Operator overloads**

```
inline PixelComponent operator+(const PixelComponent& other){
    PixelComponent result;
    result = value + other.value;
    return result;
}

inline PixelComponent operator+=(const T& elem){
    *this = *this + elem;
    return *this;
}
```

The `inline` keyword isn't necessary if we put the function definition inside the class.

`operator+=` (and the other math-assignment operators) should return a `PixelComponent&`, not a copy.

For a simple POD type, we can pass the parameter by value instead of by reference.

We'd normally implement `operator+=` to make the actual changes to the value in-place. And then implement `operator+` using `operator+=`. This saves us from making unnecessary copies (although that isn't a big deal with a single POD value).

---

```
inline bool operator<(const PixelComponent &other) {
    return !(*this > other) && *this != other;
}
```

Could be written as `return (other > *this);`

---

**Missing functions:**

```
inline PixelComponent &operator++() ...
```

Don't forget to overload the post-increment operator as well: `PixelComponent operator++(int)`

We're missing modular arithmetic operators: `a %=  b` `a % b`

We're missing the unary negation (and plus) operators: `-a` `+a`

It's reasonable to want to do bitwise operations on integer color values, so maybe we should have those too...

Comment: thank u man, such great advises, I am now struggling with implementing `struct Space` which has all this `PixelComponents` you may be interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041648/c-struct-field-name-and-types-from-variadic-template?noredirect=1#comment114988393_65041648.

Comment: Thx again for reviewing also this is the right answer with priceless advices.

Comment: The comparison operator overloads are backwards. Traditionally, they are all implemented in terms of `operator <`; here, OP has them in terms of `operator >`. By defining them in terms of `operator <` they can be used in nearly all the Standard Algorithms in the `<algorithm>` header.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really need an own class definition. Also your code doesn't do anything apart from the automatic clamping.

I would suggest using something like

```cpp
using PixelT = uint8_t;
```

somewhere in your code.
Maybe it would also be interesting to see an example of how your code is used to suggest alternatives. One alternative would surely be to use the [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) function. I guess you wouldn't have too many places in your code where you actually would add or multiply pixels. Using `std::clamp` here - or even your own version of clamp with fixed min/max values would probably work as well.

Just a few hints about "style":

1. Prefer direct initialization - or direct returns - over declaring a variable, then initializing it - e.g. writing

   ```cpp
   PixelComponent operator/(const T& elem){
     return PixelComponent(value / elem);
   }
   ```

   Of course for this to work in your example the constructor that takes a value should also clamp the value - not only the assignment operator. Otherwise your interface will stick to this awkward need to invoke the `operator=`.
2. Do not use `inline` when not necessary - this should only be necessary for definitions outside of the class body inside the header. Nowadays the compiler would optimize automatically and would not consider the `inline` keyword any more.
3. Try to define `explicit` constructors (when one argument is given) - this inhibits conversion to a different type when that was actually not intended.

See many many other rules in the [Cpp Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) - yes - this language is complicated. But have fun anyway!